# React.js: How to call function only once watching scroll position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I would like to add value to window Object(google tag manager's dataLayer) when certain component is viewable on screen. Then, need to handle calling function not to be multiple.

So, I tried to write code like below...

```
import _ from 'lodash';

export const ContentsComponent = () => {
  const DEFAULT_SCROLL_POSITION = 0;

  const [isPushed, setIsPushed] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const setScroll = (event: Event) => {
    const newScroll = (event.target as Document).documentElement.scrollTop;
    if ((newScroll > 400) && !isPushed) {
      setIsPushed(true);
      justOneceFunction()
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', _.debounce(setScroll, 1000));
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', _.debounce(setScroll, 1000));
  });

  const justOneceFunction = () => {...}
}
```

Result: isPushed state is updated `true` only for a moment, but next time updated to `false`, so `justOneceFunction()` is called multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', _.debounce(setScroll, 1000));
  },[]);
```